# Removal of special characters, a comma separated text, PHP

Tags: php, text, csv

I got my text variable which is user-specified, normally, user should enter the tags which has to look following:

```
"food, community, relationship"
```

but if user type for example

```
"food;;[]'.'.;@$#community,,,-;,,,relationship"
```

the script should change it into:

```
"food, community, relationship".
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about:

```
$str = "-----music,,,,,,,,games;'235@#%@#%media";
$arr = preg_split("/\W+/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$str = implode(', ', $arr);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
music, games, 235, media
```

You could adapt the `\W` to which characters you need to keep.

Comment: Hey, if the input is: `-----music,,,,,,,,games;'235@#%@#%media` the output is following: `, music, games, 235, media`, how can I remove the comma at the beginning?

Comment: @Lucas: use the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`. See my edited answer.

Comment: oh, thanks really cool. I google'd function array_filter, and it works also. Which one is better for now? //Thank again./

Comment: @Lucas: `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag gives an array without empty fields and `array_filter` works on a given array. My solution is made of 2 instructions, with array_filter you have 3 : `preg_split`, `array_filter` and implode. I don't know wich one is better.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace everything that isnt alphanumeric, as such:

```
preg_split('/\W+/','',$input);
```

will output

> Array ( [0] => food [1] => community [2] => relationship [3] =>
>   1123123123 )

Edit: fixed regex

Comment: But the tag can be numeric also I guess.

Comment: \W will strip everything not alphabetic or a number.

Comment: Yea, that's good, but what if user doesn't separate the each tag by comma? Fe. if user type "food;;;..community" the output should be "food, community" (will fix the illegal characters).

Comment: Ah, then you'd want to split by each non-alphanumeric character. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$content = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z,]/", "", $content);
$content = str_replace(",,", ",", $content);
$content = str_replace(",", " ,", $content);
```